# Can't get compton/picom to run with i3 manjaro (community version)

Tags: linux, manjaro, i3, compton

Here is what I get when I execute 'picom':

```
[ 03/01/20 15:24:08.887 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] Option `no-dock-shadow` is deprecated, and will be removed. Please use the wintype option `shadow` of `dock` instead.
    [ 03/01/20 15:24:08.887 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] vsync option will take a boolean from now on. "none" is interpreted as "false" for compatibility, but this will stop working soon
    [ 03/01/20 15:24:08.887 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] glx-swap-method has been deprecated since v6, your setting "undefined" should be removed.
    [ 03/01/20 15:24:08.887 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] "clear-shadow" is removed as an option, and is always enabled now. Consider removing it from your config file
    [ 03/01/20 15:24:08.887 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] "paint-on-overlay" has been removed as an option, and is enabled whenever possible
```

And 'compton':

```
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.943 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] Option `no-dock-shadow` is deprecated, and will be removed. Please use the wintype option `shadow` of `dock` instead.
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.944 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] vsync option will take a boolean from now on. "none" is interpreted as "false" for compatibility, but this will stop working soon
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.944 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] glx-swap-method has been deprecated since v6, your setting "undefined" should be removed.
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.944 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] "clear-shadow" is removed as an option, and is always enabled now. Consider removing it from your config file
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.944 parse_config_libconfig WARN ] "paint-on-overlay" has been removed as an option, and is enabled whenever possible
[ 03/01/20 15:42:33.944 session_init WARN ] This compositor has been renamed to "picom", the "compton" binary will not be installed in the future.
```

This command to check what composite manager is running shows no output:

```
inxi -Gxx | grep compositor
```

I also have this line in my i3 config file:

```
# picom
exec_always --no-startup-id picom --config ~/.config/picom/picom.conf
```

I'm not sure what they are asking me to do here as the compton command mentions that 'compton' has no been renamed to 'picom', so I thought I would just have to change the .conf file name etc. but this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is the path you added to your i3 config file =

```
# picom
exec_always --no-startup-id picom --config ~/.config/picom/picom.conf
```

For my case, the path is with a single PICOM so my path is = `picom --config ~/.config/picom.conf`

Works for me hope it helps you!